# Seeing an odd behavior with Spock and code generated from AWS API Gateway SDK

Tags: spock

When mocking up objects that were generated through the AWS API Gateway (SDK), I get an unusual behavior that is most likely a Spock Bug.

For example given the following test case:

```
def "testing api gateway"() {
  given:
  def sdk = Mock(MyAWSSDK.class)
  sdk.lookupByField("xyz") >> "result"

  when:
  def myClass = newClass(sdk)
  myClass.foo()

  then:
  1 * sdk.lookupByField(_)
}
```

In my case here, I get null pointer exception when the "1 * sdk.lookupByField(*)" is present in the test case. If I take it out and replace the then: condition with "true". The test case runs without issue. I can also add an addition line in the when: phase "sdk.lookupByField(null)" and add the "1 * sdk.lookupByField(*)" back to the "then:" phase. and it seems to work. However, this is not ideal.

This is an odd behavior with Spock and seems to be related to code generated by AWS API Gateway.

I tried both JDK version 1.8.0_202 and 11.0.1

Maven Dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
    <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.10</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
    <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.9</version>
</dependency>
```

I was planning on creating a bug with Spock but wanted to reach out to the community to see if this can be replicated. If there are any takers out there it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are presenting a test but no classes under test. Please provide a full [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) next time you ask a question on SO because in order to reproduce your problem I had to create it myself even though it would have been your job. Thank you.

There is no Spock error but there are two errors in your test code:

- What is `newClass(sdk)` supposed to do? I assume you want to create a `MyClass` object there and maybe rather wanted to write `def myClass = new MyClass(sdk)`.
- As the [Spock manual](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3-RC1/all_in_one.html#_combining_mocking_and_stubbing) explains, if you want to combine mocking and stubbing, they have to happen in the same interaction. Your assumption, that you can first write `sdk.lookupByField("xyz") >> "result"` and later `1 * sdk.lookupByField(_)` in order to set the stubbed return value first and set the number of expected calls later is thus wrong. You have to define both in the same place. Otherwise the mocked method will return `null` (default value), not `"result"`, because the first statement is overwritten by the second one.

Your solution would look like this:

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q54636103

class MyAWSSDK {
  String lookupByField(String s) {
    "real result"
  }
}
```

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q54636103

class MyClass {
  MyAWSSDK myAWSSDK

  MyClass(MyAWSSDK myAWSSDK) {
    this.myAWSSDK = myAWSSDK
  }

  String foo(String s) {
    myAWSSDK.lookupByField("xyz")
  }
}
```

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q54636103

import spock.lang.Specification

class ApiGatewayTest extends Specification {
  def "testing api gateway the wrong way"() {
    given:
    def sdk = Mock(MyAWSSDK)
    sdk.lookupByField("xyz") >> "mock result"

    when:
    def myClass = new MyClass(sdk)
    def result = myClass.foo()

    then:
    1 * sdk.lookupByField(_)
    result == "mock result"    // uh-oh!
  }

  def "testing api gateway the right way"() {
    given:
    def sdk = Mock(MyAWSSDK)

    when:
    def myClass = new MyClass(sdk)
    def result = myClass.foo()

    then:
    1 * sdk.lookupByField("xyz") >> "mock result"
    result == "mock result"    // yeah!
  }
}
```

The first feature method will fail as follows, the second will pass:

```
Condition not satisfied:

result == "mock result"    // uh-oh!
|      |
null   false
```